# Sorting dynamically JComboBox by it's items attributs in java

Tags: java, swing, sorting, dynamic, jcombobox

I would like to sort the Items of a JComboBox by it's items attributs :

I have this class :

```
public class Person {
    private static _ID;
    private _Name;
    private _FamilyName;
    public MyObject (int id, String name, String familyName){
        _ID = id;
        _Name = name;
        _FamilyName = familyName;
    }
 @Override
 public toString (){
    return _Name;
 }

}
```

And I have a JComboBox :

```
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.addItem( new Person(1,"Richard","Stallman") );
comboBox.addItem( new Person(2,"Douglas","Adams") );
comboBox.addItem( new Person(3,"Terry","Pratchett") );
comboBox.addItem( new Person(4,"Goreges","Brassens") );
```

I would like the user to choose the way he wants to sort the JComboBox:

```
    JComboBox comboBoxSort = new JComboBox();
    comboBoxSort.addItemSort("ID");
    comboBoxSort.addItemSort("Name");
    comboBoxSort.addItemSort("Family Name");
```

I don't need to change the displayed value in the JComboBox, I just need the order to change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, your Person class is syntactically wrong.  Here's a corrected version.

```
public class Person {
    private static int  _ID_COUNTER = 0;
    private int         _ID;
    private String      _Name;
    private String      _FamilyName;

    public Person(String name, String familyName) {
        _ID  = ++ID_COUNTER;
        _Name = name;
        _FamilyName = familyName;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return _Name;
    }

    public int get_ID() {
        return _ID;
    }

    public String get_Name() {
        return _Name;
    }

    public String get_FamilyName() {
        return _FamilyName;
    }

}
```

The Sorted Combo Box Model that camickr mentioned allows you to sort the Person instances in one way.  To sort the Person instances 3 different ways, you'll need to write 3 Comparator classes.  Here's one for the name.

```
public class NameSort implements Comparator<Person> {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person arg0, Person arg1) {
        int result = arg0.get_Name().compareToIgnoreCase(arg1.get_Name());
        if (result == 0) {
            return arg0.get_FamilyName().compareToIgnoreCase(
                    arg1.get_FamilyName());
        } else {
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to write the other 2 Comparator classes.

Finally, you need to sort the input to the JComboBox.  The easiest way to do this is to keep a List<Person> and pass a sorted Person[] to the JComboBox.  Here's one way to do that.

```
    public Person[] sortPersonsByName(List<Person> persons) {
        Collections.sort(persons, new NameSort());
        return persons.toArray(new Person[persons.size()]);
    }
```

This code would be called in the action listener of your sort JButton.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the [Sorted Combo Box Model](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/11/sorted-combo-box-model/).

It will sort by default on the natural sort order of the object added to the model, or you can provide a custom Comparator.